# How does the HTML specification process work?

Tags: html, specifications

I'm trying to get confirmation on understanding how the HTML specification process work.

Particularly so I can build a timeline on when elements were released.

My current understanding now is that the HTML specification releases a draft and then it's up to web browsers to adopt it right away or take their time implementing it.

Looking at this spec for the `<style>` element, it says that it is an Editor's draft from 2012.

Link: https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html

So does this mean the element was released in 2012? (I've felt like the style element was released much earlier) How can I also find out the month it got released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's up to the browsers to implement the specifications set out by W3, in their own time. Considering the lack of implementation of several elements by various browsers (which can be checked on [**CanIUse**](http://caniuse.com/)), it would indeed appear to be an almost limitless window for them to do so.

The link that you're looking at is the **development** specification - work that is ongoing.

The **[`<style>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)** in particular was included in **[HTML 4.0.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)**, which was released on 24 December 1999, with the specifics on the element found **[here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3)**. This would be the point at which the element was finalised, and released publicly. Adoption rates would differ from browser to browser.

Looking through **[the documentation for HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html#script)** (14 January 1997), you can see that the `<style>` and `<script>` elements "are place holders for the introduction of style sheets and client-side scripts in future versions of HTML".

Searching through **[the archives on CSS styling](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/)**, the earliest **ever** implementation of the `<style>` element appears to be 29 May 1995. This is when version 0.97e of W3's testbed 'Arena' browser was released, which appears to include the `<style>` element for the first time (as is referenced in [**the release notes**](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1995May/0008.html)).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this. This is very helpful. By the way what was your workflow to finding it so fast? Was there a special search area you could look for the element, or did you just have to manually go through the drafts here?: https://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_HTML

Comment: That's actually a great list, and one that I didn't stumble upon myself. Personally, I look to the Mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) for any element information (along with specifications). As for finding the earliest mention, I checked the attribute's individual W3 page (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/), and specifically the archives referenced there (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/). In the archives, it's just a matter of searching for the earliest mention :)